# How to get PhpMyAdmin to delete/truncate without asking for confirmation

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

On my local development machine, I'm always deleting rows/truncating tables, or even dropping tables/databases all the time. However I'm constantly getting messages asking to confirm.

1) Where can I edit phpmyadmin's code so it doesn't show me javascript confirm/cancel boxes when I try to delete or empty tables,

2) In the new version of phpmyadmin, the handy 'empty' and 'drop' buttons that used to be visible while you were browsing a table are now gone. How can I bring them back?

I tried to do this myself but phpmyadmin's code is pretty impossible to make sense of. I don't know where their html is kept.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it, but it looks good:

Take a look at your [config.inc.php](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php) and change:

```
$cfg['Confirm']                 = TRUE;
```

Source: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#Confirm

Comment: doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: This indeed only concerns `DROP`statements, as explained [here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#Confirm)

Answer (score 0):

I tested it already and `$cfg['Confirm']` does not work!

You just can't remove the confirmation box before dropping a table.
Even so, you can drop a database without confirmation.
This is ridiculous but this is how phpmyadmin works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from `Settings - SQL QUERIES - Confirm DROP queries` or you can set `Config` in `config.inc.php`, both are working, I have tested it now.

```php
// confirm some commands that can result in loss of data
$cfg['Confirm'] = false;
```